# HStack: onTapGesture only works on elements

Tags: swiftui

I have this example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {

            Text("part1")

            Spacer()

            Text("part2")

            Spacer()

            Text("part3")

        }
        .onTapGesture {
            print("tapped")
        }
    }
    
}
```

The problem is, that the `.onTapGesture` is only getting called, when I tap on a `Text`, but not if I tap on the space between the elements.

I tried to but a `Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)` as a background to the `HStack`, but it didn't work either (it just works, if I put i. e. `Color.blue`).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It needs to specify content shape to cover all area, because by default only opaque things handle gesture

```
}
.contentShape(Rectangle())      // << here !!
.onTapGesture {
    print("tapped")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Just found out that `.background(Rectangle().fill(Color(UIColor.systemBackground)))` would also work ;)